# Setting FLAG_SECURE does not work when added to onPause in Android

Tags: android, react-native, flag-secure

I want to Add secure Flag when app goes into background and i want to clear secure flag when app comes to foreground

but onPause is running bit late and content is not hiding in Task Switcher

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Comment: what is your requirement exactly? why do you need to clear flags when app is in foreground? can you please explain your use case?

Comment: @inkredusk I am unable to take screenshot in foreground state, that's why i want to clear secure_flag when app comes to foreground

Comment: So the user is allowed to make screen shots but Android is disallowed? If you want to allow screen shots may be the better idea is to integrate a screen shot function into your app.

Comment: @Robert is there any way to hide content with custom view when app is in background like Phone pay App doing right now?